# Change colour of each marker depending on a 4th dimension

Tags: julia, visualization, plots.jl

I've got 3 separate axes, with not many discrete values, and 3 dimensions of data: x, y and z.

[image: small graph]

The trouble is, because there aren't so many discrete values, I can't exactly see clusters in the data. What I'd like is, instead of each point being the same colour, a point being a different colour depending on how many times it occurs - like a 3d heatmap with points. For example, if (1,1,1) occurs three times, I'd like it to be redder than something that occurs once.

I've had a look at Julia's series recipe documentation, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about it. Could I get pointed in the right direction? Is there a more sensible way of visualising this?

EDIT: To show anyone looking what it ended up looking like, it was like this with the data I had:
[image: heatmapped 3D scatter plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most natural thing is to add jitter to your plot.

Data setup:

```
using Random
Random.seed!(0)
N=2000
dat=DataFrame(x=rand(1:5,N),y=rand(1:5,N),z=rand(1:5,N))
```

Plotting:

```
scatter3d(dat.x+rand(N)./10 .- 0.2, 
          dat.y+rand(N)./10 .- 0.2, 
          dat.z+rand(N)./10 .- 0.2)
```

[image]

However, if you want to use the colors this still can be done:

```
dat2=combine(groupby(dat,[:x,:y,:z]),nrow)
```

Having processed the data now let's make a colormap (you might want to adjust it differently):

```
using Colors
cols = range(colorant"red", stop=colorant"green", length=maximum(dat2.nrow))
```

Time to plot:

```
scatter3d(dat2.x, dat2.y, dat2.z, color=cols[dat2.nrow])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually learned quite a lot from this answer and looking into its parts. I did use a different colormap with more individually distinguishable parts, but apart from that this worked marvellously. I'll put the result in the question. One question though: I couldn't find any documentation for `aggregate`. I have an idea of what it does from the results, but what does it actually do?

Comment: `aggregate` is deprecated - so that is why it is not showing in docs. Now it has been replaced by `combine`  - I have updated the answer to use `combine`